# Pivot table not refreshing when named range is changing [VBA]

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pivot table which use a named range ("FP_Area") as data source. I have a code that update this named range by remove it and recreate with fresh data.

My problem is when I refresh my pivot table with the following code, it does not refresh properly and used old data from old named range ("FP_Area")

Here's how I update my pivot table:

```
Sub Test1_Refresh()

    Dim Pivot_sht As Worksheet
    Dim PivotName As String

   'Set Variables Equal to Data Sheet and Pivot Sheet
    Set Pivot_sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1")

   'Enter in Pivot Table Name
    PivotName = "Test1"

   'Change Pivot Table Data Source Range Address
    Pivot_sht.PivotTables(PivotName).ChangePivotCache _
        ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
            SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                 SourceData:="FP_Area")

   'Ensure Pivot Table is Refreshed
    Pivot_sht.PivotTables(PivotName).RefreshTable
End Sub
```

However, it still use the old "FP_Area" data.

I'm using this version: 
     Microsoft Excel 2010 (14.0.7109.5000) Part of Microsoft Office Professional 
     Plus 2018

Thanks,
Max

Comment: How are you removing the old range?

Comment: Instead of removing the Named Range I would suggest you look into creating a Dynamic Named Range by using the Offset Counta Counta formula.

Comment: And (following on from Xabier's comment) why?

Comment: This code should work. Is the name of your worksheet 1 or is it the first sheet? If it's an index you should remove the quotationmarks.

Comment: I'm removing the old range by removing the old sheets, remove range, move new sheets into my workbook and then recreate a range. Yes, my sheets name is 1. I know that my code should work, i'm suspecting something with PivotCache or something like that

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I had to use the "Offset" function when recreating my named range.

```
Dim x As String
'Retrieve the pre-built Offset function
x = Worksheets("SYS_Parameter").Range("I27")
'Create a name
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="zTest", RefersTo:=x
```

So in my previous code, if I replace "FP_Area" by "x", it's working perfectly.

Thanks